# Make difference between Select and Drag in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have some custom controls in my Canvas.

That controls can be moved by drag and drop, or selected by click.

Now, I implemented the Drag and Drop something like this:

```
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        this.isDragInProgress = false;

        // Cache the mouse cursor location.
        this.origCursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

        // Walk up the visual tree from the element that was clicked, 
        // looking for an element that is a direct child of the Canvas.
        var source = e.Source;

        var element = this.FindCanvasChild(source as DependencyObject);

        if (element == null || !(element is MyControl))
            return;

        this.ElementBeingDragged = element;

        // Get the element's offsets from the four sides of the Canvas.
        this.draggedLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(this.ElementBeingDragged);
        this.darggedTop = Canvas.GetTop(this.ElementBeingDragged);

        // Set the Handled flag so that a control being dragged 
        // does not react to the mouse input.
        e.Handled = true;

        this.isDragInProgress = true;
    }
```

Now, my problem is that I can't select MyControl clicking on it... (there is no MouseClick event on the custom Control, nor MouseDown works now..)

If I'll comment `e.Handled = true;` the control will change it selection when dragging, if don't comment it, the control will not change it selection at all.... (

Answer (score 8):

Rather than beginning the drag operation in a MouseDown handler, you can save some initial state and instead commit to dragging in a MouseMove handler, where you can check against `SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance` and `SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance` to see if there has been enough movement to begin a drag operation. You can then include code in a MouseUp handler to either complete the drag operation or, if it never started because the movement was too small, do a select instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a code project article that might help you.  The article is about drag selection and multiple item dragging.

In the MouseMove event handler there is code that tests for the user dragging further than the threshold distance, when this happens the drag operation is initiated.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SimpleDragSelection.aspx